# m2Eclipse plugin with maven 3.0.3, no compilation errors, and jre5 with jdk7

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, java-7

Question about the m2 eclipse plugin.  Currently I have "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers", the most recent update.  I have the m2 eclipse plugin installed, and have started a normal java project.  I then converted this to a maven project via

"right click->configure->convert to to maven project"
This appears to work, a pom.xml is created, the project converts, and everything is well and good.

The issue starts when I do anything to this project.  In the maven settings for the project "Right client on project -> maven" there are several options that are behaving strangely, updating maven configuration will change the default JDK for the project (JDK7) to j2SE-1.5..., which was never installed on the machine, and of course is not found.  Also code completion, and and error checking is not working in the editor.

Example:
params.put("some_string", ); This should render "red" for compilation errors because there is no second argument to put(), however this checks out as okay according to the eclipse editor.

I have some done some research on this issue, and from what I can gather from Google, it appears that there are some issues with m2eclipse and this distro of eclipse however there is nothing to resolve this.  Is anybody else having similar problems, or does anybody have any idea how to resolve this?

Please let me know if the is any other information I can provide, I didn't want to just paste my settings.xml into stack overflow.

Note: I have my settings.xml configured in Eclipse, and have specifies which jdk to use (7)

System information:
Maven version: 3.0.3
Eclipse Version: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version

All eclipse plugins have the most recent versions installed as of this post date, and there are no XML integrity errors, or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer to this is the answer to so many other questions on Stack overflow and other sites....  "mvn eclipse:eclipse".  I was under the impression that Eclipse "did this for you" on project startup, and that is apparently not the case.  After running that on a brand new work-space after an eclipse re-install (new computer) everything works fine.

I felt the need to close this one out.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

For the JDK issue: in your pom.xml specify

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then do another "Update Project configuration". Then the JDK 7 should be set (at least works for me).

Comment: no such luck, converting still reverts to jdk 5.  Also I should not that typing in a class that you would normally be able to click on and auto resolve via Maven, does not work on top of the no errors.  No options appear at all (create class named this, add annotation, etc...)

Comment: Sorry to keep adding stuff, but I should also add that Maven otherwise appears to be working.  For any of the Maven repositories in the eclipse repositories window, I can rebuild indexes, enable full/minimum indexing, and all of that appears to be working, no errors in the console or anywhere else to my knowledge.

Comment: Just trying to get as much information on here as possible.  I created a new base maven project for testing.  This one defaulted to j2SE5, which again, is not installed.  I simple removed it and added JDK7 (default) into the build path.  I can go into the pom.xml dependency management viewer and search for dependency's, and add them, log4j for example.  However when I implement the class in the works space, they do not resolve in the work-space, and there is no option to resolve that dependency.  This particular project does render red errors for compilation errors though.